# OutOfMemoryException: Недостаточно памяти

Tags: .net, delphi, bitmap, graphics, gdi+

Проблема: Мне нужно создать объект `bitmap` класса `System.Drawing.Bitmap` с `PixelFormat` = `Format16bppGrayScale`.

```
bitmap := new System.Drawing.Bitmap(32, 32, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
```

Сам `bitmap` создается, однако при создании объекта `System.Drawing.Graphics` через статичную функцию `Graphics.FromImage(bitmap)` мне выводит ошибку: *"Недостаточно памяти"* (такая же ошибка с форматом пикселей `Format16bppArgb1555`).

```
graphics := System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
```

Я залез в *GDIView*, чтобы проверить, нет ли утечки памяти, однако *TotalGDIObjects* не доходил и до 1000. Я попробовал создать `bitmap` с другим форматом пикселей (`Format16bppRgb565`, `Format16bppRgb555`, `Format24bppRgb`, `Format32bppArgb565` и др.), и ошибка исчезла!

Вопрос: Почему происходит эта ошибка, и почему не со всеми форматами пикселей?

Код:

```
<...>
var
  bitmap: System.Drawing.Bitmap;
  graphics: System.Drawing.Graphics;

begin

  bitmap := new System.Drawing.Bitmap(32, 32, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
  graphics := System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

end.
```

Comment: `bitmap := new ...`  Вы точно на Delphi пишете?

Comment: Похоже на какой-нибудь ABCPascal.NET

Comment: Видимо, проблема в том, что формат BMP не умеет хранить такие форматы пикселей. Для 16 бит на пиксель в оттенках серого попробуйте PNG или TIFF.

Comment: Мне кажется, что проблема в том, что система не умеет отображать картинки с 16 битами на канал. Видимо нужно как-то конвертировать в 8 бит для отображения на экране. Хотя говорят ещё про WIC http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_4426.html (может там это решено).

Comment: С другой стороны: Windows GDI+ version 1.0 can read 16-bits-per-channel images, but such images are converted to an 8-bits-per-channel format for processing, displaying, and saving.